# I want to express mechanical movements, but I'm having difficulty

Tags: animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yl8PsvZtcE8

I want to depict a circular cylinder and a plate moving along a path and fitting together, like in the example video. I just can't seem to do it. Can you please provide some guidance?

Comment: what did u try? did u try curve modifier?

Comment: Please record or post image of what you have tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: could you please tell at what minute of your video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a curve (1), a mechanic piece (2) and a subdivided plane (3) that has a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Parent the piece to the plane, select the plane and in the *Object* panel > *Instancing*, click on *Faces* so that the piece is instanced on each face of the plane. Also, in the same panel, disable its visibility:

[image]

Move the plane on the correct axis (here on X):

[image]

As the object is actually made of 2 pieces, duplicate your plane, offset it a bit, create your second piece and parent it to this second plane:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm glad I could help you resolve it.